# Is compact subset of a metric space a compact metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Definition: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. We say $K \subseteq X$ is a compact subset of $X$ if every open cover for $K$ has a finite sub-cover.

Fact: $(K,d')$ can be regarded as a metric space where $d'$ is restriction of $d$.

Question: If $K$ is a compact subset of $(X,d)$. Is $(K,d')$ a compact space?

Comment: What keeps you from sayng that it "obviously" is?

Comment: Do you know the characterization of open subsets in $(K, d')$? They are precisely those $V\subseteq K$ for which there is an open subset $U\subseteq X$ such that $V = U\cap K$.

Comment: @Jakobian Thank you for the information. I didn't know that, but I know how to answer my question with that information. Can you elaborate on how is that characterization true?

Comment: @JohnFrank oh, you can just prove it. Use that $B_K(x, r) = X\cap B_X(x, r)$ to show that. Note that the open balls $B(x, r)$ are open from triangle inequality. Here $B_K(x, r)$ denotes the open ball of $(K, d')$, and $B_X(x, r)$ the open ball of $(X, d)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subspace topology for any compact subset of a space is compact.

Likewise, if a space is compact and is mapped continuously into another space, including if it is embedded as a subspace, then that image/embedding is a compact subset of the space.